# Golang: tests and working directory

Tags: unit-testing, go, working-directory

I'm writing some unit tests for my application in Go. The tests fail however because it cannot find the configuration files. Normally the binary looks for the configuration files in the working directory under the path `conf/*.conf`.

I figured that browsing to the directory that has `conf/` and running `go test` in it would solve it, but it still reports that the file system cannot find the path specified.

How can I tell `go test` to use a certain directory as the working directory so that the tests may actually be executed?

Comment: If your unit tests depend on configuration, they aren't unit tests.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You may be able to use the Caller to get the path to the current test source file, like this:

```
package sample

import (
    "testing"
    "runtime"
    "fmt"
)

func TestGetFilename(t *testing.T) {
    _, filename, _, _ := runtime.Caller(0)
    t.Logf("Current test filename: %s", filename)
}
```

Comment: Agreed, this is a very nice way to to do it. Combine with the Dir function from package "path/filepath" to build a path relative the input go file's folder.

Comment: Note that Caller retuns the package name if the tests are run using `go test github.com/the/package`. I'm trying to package a go application for nixpkgs and this is giving me some trouble.

Answer (score 31):

I do not believe this is possible. I have not been able to find documentation stating this explicitly, but I believe `go test` always uses the package directory (containing the go source files) as the working directory.

Comment: Thanks, that's very annoying but I suppose there's no way around it. I'll probably add a bug report/suggestion to the Go project to perhaps add a `-w $d` or `--working-dir=$d` parameter to `go test`.

Comment: There should absolutely be some documentation here -- hopefully it's actually a guarantee :).

Answer (score 22):

As a workaround, I compiled the test and execute the test from the current directory.

`go test -c && ./<mypackage>.test`

Or, if you want a generic command that you can use, you can rename the test file with `-o` option.

`go test -c -o xyz.test && ./xyz.test`

Comment: This is the best answer for me!
I could run my tests from the same dir where my binary usually runs from.

Comment: This works, does anyone know how to integrate it with vscode?

Answer (score 17):

No matter where the work directory is. It must be under your project Dir. So my solution is

```
wd, _ := os.Getwd()
for !strings.HasSuffix(wd, "<yourProjectDirName>") {
    wd = filepath.Dir(wd)
}

raw, err := ioutil.ReadFile(fmt.Sprintf("%s/src/conf/conf.dev.json", wd))
```

Your path should always start from your project Dir. Every time you read the file in a package and accessed by main.go or your another package unit test. It will always work.

Comment: This is very nice, but won't work if you have the (pretty common) pattern of using `pkgname/cmd/pkgname`.

Comment: You can try smaller `wd = strings.SplitAfter(wd, "<yourProjectDirName>")[0]`

Answer (score 13):

While not really convenient, you can always pass it as a command line variable, for example :

```
package blah_test

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "testing"
)

var (
    cwd_arg = flag.String("cwd", "", "set cwd")
)

func init() {
    flag.Parse()
    if *cwd_arg != "" {
        if err := os.Chdir(*cwd_arg); err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Chdir error:", err)
        }
    }
}

func TestBlah(t *testing.T) {
    t.Errorf("cwd: %+q", *cwd_arg)
}
```

Then run it like :

```
┌─ oneofone@Oa [/tmp]                                                                                             
└──➜ go test . -cwd="$PWD"
--- FAIL: TestBlah (0.00 seconds)
        blah_test.go:16: cwd: "/tmp"
```

Comment: That's a good idea. I'm curious though, what command prompt is that you're using?

Comment: I'm using fish, the specific function to show the prompt is @ https://github.com/OneOfOne/etc-fish/blob/master/functions/fish_prompt.fish

Answer (score 11):

To add init function into *_test.go under your test package.
Test package will run this function before test function start.

```
func init() {
    _, filename, _, _ := runtime.Caller(0)
    // The ".." may change depending on you folder structure
    dir := path.Join(path.Dir(filename), "..")
    err := os.Chdir(dir)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }  
}
```

Comment: I had assumed that go ran the tests in the same directory as the source code being tested, but at least as of go version 1.15.5, the tests are compiled in a temporary directory under /tmp (e.g. /tmp/go-build549268541) and with a working directory of /tmp.  So `os.Chdir("..")` will not work anymore.

the answer using `runtime.Caller(0)` seems like the way to go.

Comment: I like to add it in a `testing` package, and just import it like "_ yourmod/testing" for all tests

Answer (score 10):

You can use the [os package](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Chdir).

You would want to do something like this

```
    func TestMyFunction(t *testing.T) {
        os.Chdir("./path")

        //TEST FUNCTION

        os.Chdir("..")
    }
```

There are several possibilities in the os package.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not seem to work when the source code contains `*template.Must(...)` calls to compile HTML templates.

Answer (score 4):

I currently use a neat solution for this problem, instead of opening the file directly by calling `os.Open()`, I use the embed package in a smart way:

First I create a global variable in my root package called:

```golang
//go:embed config/* otherdirectories/*
var RootFS embed.FS
```

Then I just open the files inside my tests by using this global variable, e.g.:

```golang
func TestOpenConfig(t *testing.T) {
    configFile, err := rootpkg.RootFS.ReadFile("config/env")
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("unable to open config/env file: %s", err)
    }

    if string(configFile) != "FOO=bar\n" {
        t.Fatalf("config file contents differ from expected: %s", string(configFile))
    }
}
```

This is a neat trick because now you can always work with relative paths from your root package, which is what I used to do in other programming languages.

Of course, this has the restriction that you will need to import your root package, which depending on your package layout might not be ideal because of cyclic imports. If this is your case you might just create a `embed.go` file inside the config directory itself.

One other drawback is that you are embedding test files in your binary, this is probably ok if your test files are not very big, like megabytes big, so I don't really mind this issue.

I also created a repository for illustrating this solution:

https://github.com/VinGarcia/golang-reading-files-from-tests

Answer (score 3):

Go 1.20 is getting new `-C` arguments for "go subcommands" so this should help:

```
go test -C directory/ ...
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but I had the same problem trying to use migrations for the database on my tests, and maybe this solution helps someone.

Since there is no native way of getting the project directory, you could identify some file or directory that you know it's only in the root of the project (in my case, it was the relative directory **database/migrations**). Once you have this unique relative directory, you could have a function like the following to obtain the project root directory. It just gets the current working directory (assuming it's inside the project's directory) and starts to navigate all the way up until it finds a dir that has the relative directory you know it's on the root of the project:

```
func FindMyRootDir() string {
    workingDirectory, err := os.Getwd()

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    lastDir := workingDirectory
    myUniqueRelativePath := "database/migrations"

    for {
        currentPath := fmt.Sprintf("%s/%s", lastDir, myUniqueRelativePath)

        fi, err := os.Stat(currentPath)

        if err == nil {
            switch mode := fi.Mode(); {
            case mode.IsDir():
                return currentPath
            }
        }

        newDir := filepath.Dir(lastDir)

        // Ooops, we couldn't find the root dir. Check that your "myUniqueRelativePath" really exists

        if newDir == "/" || newDir == lastDir {
            return ""
        }

        lastDir = newDir
    }
}
```

Of course it's not the most beautiful solution, but it works.

Comment: You can check for the `.git` folder which almost always means parent folder

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem and found the solution [on this blog](https://brandur.org/fragments/testing-go-project-root)

Basically you can change the folder that the test is running using a similar function:

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "path"
    "runtime"
)

func MakeFunctionRunOnRootFolder() {
    _, filename, _, _ := runtime.Caller(0)
    // The ".." may change depending on you folder structure
    dir := path.Join(path.Dir(filename), "..")
    err := os.Chdir(dir)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a common practice in Go to place test fixtures **in same package** inside `testdata` folder.

Some examples from standard library:

- [debug/elf](https://golang.org/src/debug/elf/)
- [net/http](https://golang.org/src/net/http/)
- [image](https://golang.org/src/image/)

Also, there is a [post](https://dave.cheney.net/2016/05/10/test-fixtures-in-go) from Dave Cheney, where he suggests following code:

```golang
f, err := os.Open("testdata/somefixture.json")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is function to find a root project directory that contains .git folder:

```
import (
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
)

func FindProjectDir() string {
    // Test can be started from command line in project folder or in IDE
    // Try to detect a correct path to a project directory

    // Find a project dir that contains .git
    curDir, _ := os.Getwd()
    projectDir := curDir
    for {
        _, err := os.Stat(projectDir + "/.git")
        if err == nil {
            break
        }
        projectDir = filepath.Dir(projectDir)
        if projectDir == "/" { // reached root
            return ""
        }
    }
    return ""
}
```

You can adapt it and append the file name that you are looking for.
Still I think this answer is better https://stackoverflow.com/a/71488632/1049542
But sometime you need also to execute some shell script in the project root folder so you need to know the parent folder.

Answer (score -1):

I would use an Environment Variable for the location of your application.  It seems to be the best way when running go tools, as test programs can be run from a temporary location.

```
// get home dir of app, use MYAPPHOME env var if present, else executable dir.
func exeDir() string {
    dir, exists := os.LookupEnv("MYAPPHOME")
    if exists {
        return dir
    } else {
        ex, err := os.Executable()
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        exPath := path.Dir(ex)
        return exPath
    }
}
```