# Why is goapp test is looking for files in /tmp?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I'm trying to get tests working on my local dev machine Cloud SDK version is: 159.0.0

Everything I've read says that I should no change GOROOT so I'm not sure how to fix this.

$ /Users/bryan/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/goroot/bin/goapp test

```
go: cannot find GOROOT directory: /tmp/go_sdk887571938/appengine/go_appengine/goroot
```

bryan@Bryans-MacBook Thu Jun 15 10:22:37 ~/go/src/skincarereview

$ go env

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/bryan/go/"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT="1"
CC="clang"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fno-common"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

bryan@Bryans-MacBook Thu Jun 15 10:22:57 ~/go/src/skincarereview

$ ls ~/google-cloud-sdk

```
total 408
drwxr-xr-x  30 bryan  staff    1020 Jun 14 20:31 .install
-rw-r--r--   1 bryan  staff     980 Jun 14 20:30 LICENSE
-rw-r--r--   1 bryan  staff     673 Jun 14 20:30 README
-rw-r--r--   1 bryan  staff  162673 Jun 14 20:30 RELEASE_NOTES
-rw-r--r--   1 bryan  staff       8 Jun 14 20:30 VERSION
drwxr-xr-x  10 bryan  staff     340 Jun 14 20:30 bin
-rw-r--r--   1 bryan  staff    2734 Jun 14 20:30 completion.bash.inc
-rw-r--r--   1 bryan  staff    2083 Jun 14 20:30 completion.zsh.inc
drwxr-xr-x   3 bryan  staff     102 Jun 14 20:30 help
-rwxr-xr-x   1 bryan  staff    1581 Jun 14 20:30 install.bat
-rwxr-xr-x   1 bryan  staff    3471 Jun 14 20:30 install.sh
drwxr-xr-x  10 bryan  staff     340 Jun 14 20:30 lib
-rw-r--r--   1 bryan  staff     308 Jun 14 20:30 path.bash.inc
-rw-r--r--   1 bryan  staff    1210 Jun 14 20:30 path.fish.inc
-rw-r--r--   1 bryan  staff      31 Jun 14 20:30 path.zsh.inc
drwxr-xr-x   6 bryan  staff     204 Jun 14 20:30 platform
-rw-r--r--   1 bryan  staff      40 Jun 14 20:30 properties
```

bryan@Bryans-MacBook Thu Jun 15 10:24:22 ~/go/src/skincarereview

$ find / -name goroot 2>/dev/null

```
/Users/bryan/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/goroot
```

bryan@Bryans-MacBook Thu Jun 15 10:28:43 ~/go/src/skincarereview

$ echo $PATH

```
/Users/bryan/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/Users/bryan/go/src/:/Users/bryan/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/goroot/bin/:/Users/bryan/google-cloud-sdk/bin/:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin
```

Looking at main.go line 155, where I think the error is being thrown, I don't see where "goroot" is being set .

```
if fi, err := os.Stat(goroot); err != nil || !fi.IsDir() {
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "go: cannot find GOROOT directory: %v\n", goroot)
    os.Exit(2)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and follow the [recommendation of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43641355/6309):

> If your install is messed up beyond reason (happened to me once), just remove the cloud SDK and any references to it in your `$PATH`. Also completely uninstall the regular Go installation.
>
> Then start from scratch. [Install Go, unpack google-cloud-sdk](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/download), run installer (add to `$PATH` if needed), `gcloud components install app-engine-go`.
> Voila.

As mentioned in that same answer, you don't set `GOROOT` anywhere, [it is set for you](https://dave.cheney.net/2013/06/14/you-dont-need-to-set-goroot-really).

Comment: I've already reinstalled from scratch on 2 separate computers. I get the same error.

Comment: @BryanWheelock OK. I suppose the first part of the answer I reference does not help either?

Comment: I had deleted GO and PATH as well. 
I sent something to Google and the problem is a bug in the SDK code. I'm not sure when the update will be.

Comment: @BryanWheelock OK. What is the URL of your bug?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read up on how go run/test works. The program basically builds into a temporary location and then runs, so that might be why it's complaining about your goroot.

This question could possibly help you: [Golang: tests and working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23847003/golang-tests-and-working-directory)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are calling wrong goapp. You should be calling one that is directly in google_appengine folder as follows:

```
/Users/bryan/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/goapp test
```

If you don't have goapp in google_appengine for some reason, I'll be quite surprised, but then following should work too. (Still the above is the correct way of calling it. goapp resolves appengine's goroot as a relative path from it's own location, so it's important where goapp itself is located.)

```
GOROOT=/Users/bryan/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/goroot /Users/bryan/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/goapp test
```