# Use relative path in init function cannot be found in test

Tags: testing, go

I'm running into an annoying problem when using relative path in the init function which cannot be found by the unit test.

Say I have a project structured like:

```
.
├── conf
│   └── blacklist
├── filter
│   ├── filter.go
│   └── filter_test.go
```

And in the `init` function of `filter.go`, I try to load the blacklist by using relative path `conf/blacklist` to avoid loading it multiple times.
Since the default working directory is exactly the project root directory, it works well with compiled binary. However `filter_test.go` will panic by
`panic: open conf/blacklist: no such file or directory`, becasue go test always uses the package directory as the working directory.

I also referred [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28200371/3004217), which could dynamically build the relative path to find the config file. It did work well until I add the `covermode=set` flag and try to do some coverage testing. It seems that the `covermode` would rewrite and generate some middle packages like `_obj`, which makes the dynamical relative path not working any more.

Has anyone run into the same problem before? I'm still new to golang for a couple of months. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Make the path to your blacklist a command line flag or read it from an environment variable.

Comment: @Volker Yeah, command line flag or using ENV should be a workaround. Just wonder, is there a solution can fix it without changing anything out of box. Also, should loading conf by relative path in init function be regarded as a bad idea?

Comment: "should loading conf by relative path in init function be regarded as a bad idea?" Yes. Because it cannot work. relative paths are relative to the current working directory during execution and totally unrelated to your code layout.

Comment: What about running the tests using something like `SRC_ROOT=$PWD go test` and then use `os.Getenv("SRC_ROOT")` to get the path.

Comment: @MattiasWadman Yeah, that's exactly the best solution right now for me.

Comment: @angeldsWang Nice. That is what i do in a project, feels simpler and safer then messing around with go internals :)  I wrote it as a proper answer. Let me know if it needs some tweaking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution is to run tests using something like `SRC_ROOT=$PWD go test` and then inside the test that want to access files use `os.Getenv("SRC_ROOT")`.

Comment: This should be an accepted answer for common cases. However, my case is, in a legacy project, the conf file has been loaded in the init function by using a relative path, that force me to use the Getenv for testing and leave the relative path for running code. Of course, I can refactor all things to using command line flags, but it costs too much for me. :(